# I want to give users ten coins each time they create a post on my blog in django but it's not giving them automatically

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, web-development-server

I have tried alot of codes yet none of them have worked so I decided to leave the views unrelated to my models.py
My question is:

I want to give users ten coins each time they create a post on my blog in django but it's not giving them automatically

Here's my views.py below

```
def journal_create_view(request):
    form = JournalModelForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.Country = request.user.profile.your_country
        obj.slug = obj.Your_Post_Title
        obj.profile_pix = request.user.profile.image
        obj.save()
        return redirect('/journal/')
        form = JournalModelForm()
    template_name = 'add_post.html'
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

**Here is my models.py**

```
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False,null=False)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
    phone = models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
    your_country = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)    
    image = models.ImageField(blank=False,null=False, upload_to="profile_image")
    coins = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**And lastly, here's my forms.py**

```
    class Meta():
        model = Profile
        fields = [
        'coins'
        ]
```

I will be of gratitude if anyone help me out

Comment: Where in the code that you have given do you think you are adding coins to the person account ?

Answer (score 1):

You can give the user the coins in the view action that adds the journal that you posted here, like this:

```
...
obj.profile_pix = request.user.profile.image
obj.save()

# Gives the user 10 coins for creating a journal
profile = obj.user.profile
profile.coins += 10
profile.save()
return redirect('/journal/')
...
```

This will work, although I would rather use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/) for this behaviour.
Using signals, you'd give the user 10 coins for creating the journal every time django saves a new instance, not only by the view action. If by any chance you write another piece of code that creates a journal, I'm guessing you'd still want to give the user 10 coins.
To do this, simply add to your journal model:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver([post_save], sender=JournalModel)
def gives_user_coins_after_create(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile = instance.user.profile
        profile.coins += 10
        profile.save()
```